# How to show an image right in the center of the whole page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

A simple demo would be sweet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like more of a styling question than anything else.  You'll need to tweak the style settings to get it exactly right.

```
img.centered
{
  position: fixed;
  left: 45%;
  top: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
}

document.ready
(
  function()
  {
    $("body").append("<img src='test.jpg' class='centered' />");
  }
);
```